# Can I disable others from receiving notifications every single time I post on FB?

Tags: facebook

Annoying family member has "Get Notifications" set on my profile.  Is there a way to stop them from receiving notifications every time I post?  Not talking about things not showing in news feed, or on the activity sidebar, just so they aren't immediately notified every time I post something.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible without limiting their ability to see the posts. You can only hide the posts from them, but as they have access to the posts, there is no way for you to prevent them to personalize the way they get their content on Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the friend onto your 'restricted' list (via your friends list) and this will only allow them to see public posts.

Answer (score -2):

You can choose friend by friend who you share with.  If you want to share with everyone but your family that would be a pain to go through.  On the privacy option you have *World*, *Friends of Friends*, *Friends*, and *Specific People*.